# FileNotFound: Access Denied

Tags: java, windows

I have a new windows 10 machine. Tomcat throwing the error -

```
    FileNotFoundException - Access Denied
```

while writing application log. I am able to create folders or save file in the same path but when i try to do that programmatic, its throwing the error

```
    Access Denied
```

When i checked 'canWrite()' on the path its returning true.

```
    canWrite:true
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\<User>\logs (Access is denied)
```

I tried giving 'full control' to the folder but didn't help.

Any pointers ?
Thanks!

Comment: Where is your folder? Inside `Program Files`? If so, the UAT is interfering, because Tomcat is not running "as administrator".

Comment: its under C:\\Users\\<myaccount>

Comment: 1. Reboot and retry (I have seen exact the same in a Windows Domain environment. After reboot it works.);

Answer (score 0):

1. Reboot and retry (I have seen exact the same in a Windows Domain environment. After reboot it works.);
2. Is the tomcat started as a service, or as standalone app? Check the user who own the tomcat process;
3. If both failed, try to delete the log folder, to see if any other process locks the log folder;
4. At last, you can use process monitor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to drill into the internal data from windows, to see what really happens.